# IntelliJ IDEA : support both SBT and Maven on a single project

Tags: java, scala, maven, intellij-idea, sbt

I already have a project in IntelliJ IDEA based on SBT. It works fine, compile and run. Now I want to add the Maven support as well.
How is it possible in IntelliJ IDEA having support for both build managers SBT and Maven in the same project and switch between them ?

Comment: why one would want to do that?

Comment: but my question was if it's possible not if it does make sense. It could be possible that the project is used by different people who prefer using different build managers.

Comment: and you expect them to add dependencies in 2 files each time? in pom and in sbt? it's cumbersome and error-prone 100%, so my question is the same, why one would want to do that?

Comment: it's cumbersome  ... but is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience you should have either maven or sbt enabled. Never both.

The solution:

- checkout project from repository to `project_sbt` directory
- open project in intellij as sbt project (just open `project_sbt/build.sbt` from disk)
- checkout the same project from repository project to `project_maven` directory.
- open project in intellij as maven project (just open `project_maven/pom.xml` from disk)

Disadvantages of this solution:

- Changes in sbt project are not visible immediately in maven project (and vice versa)
- You have to maintenance two build systems (special plugins)

Comment: I know that it's cumbersome but thank you very much for your reply ! So the only way is opening the same project two times : as SBT ans as Maven. IntelliJ doesn't provide a way to switch from one to another. Thanks !

Comment: I would consider it much more than cumbersome for any slightly more complex project. The build system is the managing instance that shall stay in command and control of your project. To have two systems  trying to keep a project under control may lead to very weird build results. So that is the reason IMHO why there is no simple switch.